# composer - how to install/prioritise specific packages first before the other packages?

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, composer-plugin

I'd been setting up [WordPress and obtaining its required plugins via composer](https://composer.rarst.net/) for some years now, it works great, but I've given up trying to hack or be tricky when it comes to installing plugins that does not know how to use `WP_SITEURL` and also PaaS that doesn't support non-standard WordPress folder structure.

So I am wondering if I can still use composer to setup WordPress-core (or any other package) but I want it to be installed first.

Say in your `composer.json`, you have the following packages:

```
{
    "name": "test/composer-install-order",
    "type": "project",
    "repositories": [
    { "type": "composer", "url": "https://wpackagist.org" }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2",
        "composer/installers": "~1.6.0",
        "johnpbloch/wordpress": "^4.9",
        "wpackagist-plugin/better-search-replace": "*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/bugherd": "*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/disable-emojis": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "public_html/wp-content/plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"],
        "public_html/wp-content/themes/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-theme"]
    },
    "wordpress-install-dir": "public_html"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "sort-packages": true
    }
}
```

The `composer.json` above says you required **3 plugins:** *better-search-replace, bugherd, and disable-emojis*

But when you hit `composer install`:

```
➜  temp1 composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 7 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
- Installing composer/installers (v1.6.0): Loading from cache
- Installing johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer (1.0.0.2): Loading from cache
- Installing wpackagist-plugin/better-search-replace (1.3.2): Loading from cache
- Installing wpackagist-plugin/bugherd (1.0.0.0): Loading from cache
- Installing johnpbloch/wordpress-core (4.9.8): Loading from cache
- Installing johnpbloch/wordpress (4.9.8): Loading from cache
- Installing wpackagist-plugin/disable-emojis (1.7.2): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
➜  temp1
```

You'll only get **1 plugin** inside `wp-content/plugins` folder. The reason for this is because when you check the print above, the 2 plugins `better-search-replace` and `bugherd` where installed first BEFORE the Wordpress core files `johnpbloch/wordpress`. So even `composer` extracted those 2 plugin packages to its correct folder, the `johnpbloch/wordpress` has removed them because it overwrote the `wp-content/plugins` folder.

The only way for this to work is if I install `johnpbloch/wordpress` first before the plugins, but I do not know if its possible since composer install via the `composer.lock` content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maintainer here. As suggested, OP opened an issue here: https://github.com/johnpbloch/wordpress-core/issues/14

I wanted to link to it (and copy it below) here so that if anybody happens upon this issue in the future there's an answer that sheds some light on what's going on. :)

Response copied from the github issue:

> Hi The Wolf,
>
> Thanks for asking your question. The issue at root here is a conflict
>   between how Composer works and the default way WordPress works.
>
> If you want to use Composer to manage WordPress core as a dependent
>   package, you have to use a specific non-standard installation option
>   for WordPress in which core is installed in a subdirectory and the
>   wp-content directory is set to a location outside of the core package.
>   Rarst [has a great microsite detailing the optimal
>   setup](https://composer.rarst.net/). You can also check out [my sample
>   WordPress package starter
>   package](https://github.com/johnpbloch/wordpress-project) for
>   inspiration. You can read more about [installing core in a
>   subdirectory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Method_II_.28With_URL_change.29)
>   and [moving
>   wp-content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder)
>   on the codex.
>
> If you're interested in reading a little more about the reasoning for
>   this issue, please see [this thread in the installer
>   repository](https://github.com/johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer/issues/20)
>   in which the topic gets a bit more lengthy treatment.
>
> Hope that helps!

Comment: John P Bloch himself ;) but I'll appreciate it if you remove my name on the quote

Comment: Terribly sorry. I updated it to use your name from here. :)

Answer (score 1):

> the `johnpbloch/wordpress` has removed them because it overwrote the `wp-content/plugins` folder

When packages start to behave like this, I do not know what people even expect anymore. I would recommend you submit an issue or a pull request to modify this behaviour, because it seems questionable at best, and just plain malicious if I am being honest.

Are you positive this is not a misconfiguration error on your side in regards to plugin paths or wordpress installer paths?

Comment: It's not really malicious on the part of the plugin - it's just a byproduct of WordPress's lack of built-in composer support.